# Magento Checkout per product

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout

I need a solution for checkout per product.
In my website there is two type of product Heavy and Normal.
For Heavy we using Fedex.
For Samll we using Southeastern.

Now on cart page I want to button as well as functionality of Per Product Checkout.
You can say product wise checkout.
Step--

If i added two product in cart small and heavy.
Then first i want to seprate checkout for Heavy one.
Then on second checkout small one.

Pls advice me any extension or possibility or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your Cart in two different Carts as soon as you fire the "go to checkout" event. (if you need the complete event name of the "to checkout site" event i can check in my code later on, or you can google it :))

You're able to make an observer, that listens to that event and interfere there, get the products of your current cart, split those into "heavy" and "normal", make 2 different Carts out of them, save those carts as a reference (in your DB or as a post parameter or however it fits you) and now proceed to the checkout for the first cart. As soon as the first cart submits the "success" event start the checkout for the second checkout. Another Observer that catches this event and checks either "is there another cart that needs to be checked out" - or just simply gets the saved quote in your post parameters/db - and triggers another checkout, but now with the second cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition on add to cart before.

If heavy product in cart and user add Normal then you can restrict them and say first checkout with heavy product.

same thing you can do for Normal